# Points cut at half at the edges of top and bottom, at chartjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, configuration, chart.js

[image]

As showed in the picture the points are cut in half when reaching bottom or top edges (when the data is 1 or 5 in this example).

I tried padding, adding some 'fake' data to extend the limits of 1 and 5 and removing it with callback function on ticks. None worked as expected

This is my config for this chart.

```
const config = {
    type: 'line' as ChartType,
    data: data,
    options: {
      pointStyle: 'circle',
      //pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
      scales: {
        y: {
          ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: 5,
            stepSize: 1,
          },
          min: 1,
          max: 5,
          reverse: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Removing min and max, results in the expected output.
[image]

But I need min and max, cause I want fixed Y axes values

Any clues how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `afterDataLimits` hook to set the max and min of the scale, that way it still overflows the chart area:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [12, 19, 3, 10, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink',
      backgroundColor: 'pink',
      radius: 10
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        afterDataLimits: (scale) => {
          scale.max = 10;
          scale.min = 0;
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart" width="250" height="120" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That worked great! Thxs.
Do you think that is a bug with min and max?

Comment: Not sure, if so I think it's more a bug in the workaround I provided because with max you say don't show anything above this point so an overflow would violate that

Answer (score 0):

With Chart.js@3 or greater the options `clip` property will prevent this [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6414), and you can still have `min` and `max` values provided.

```
options: {
  clip: false,
  scales: {
    x: {},
    y: { max: 10 }
  }
}
```